# Not able to get the Cycle, Execution ID using Zephyr squad Rest APIs

Tags: jira-rest-api, jql, jira-zephyr

I have created JWT from postman using URL https://prod-vortexapi.zephyr4jiracloud.com/api/v1/jwt/generate POST request by putting accessKey, secretKey, and accountId as header. I am trying to access the

https://prod-play.zephyr4jiracloud.com/connect/public/rest/api/1.0/executions/search/cycle/

but getting an error as

{"error": "API not found."}

Please help i need to fetch all latest cycle and test cases execution id to execute and after that i need to update the test cases status using API.